# Is it considered spam to set "From: " header to the user's email in a contact form?

Tags: email, forms, best-practices

I developed a contact form on a client's website. When a user submits it, the client gets an email.

Is it considered as spam (or against best practices) when emails sent from a website form have `From: user_s_own_email@gmail.com` header (with user's real address)?

The alternative is to have `From: info@customers-website.com` and a `Reply-to: user_s_own_email@gmail.com`, which is also not perfect usability-wise (if the client uses an email client that doesn't understand reply-to), but I don't know if that is better given that the other option might get marked as spam.

Comment: Setting the From address to match the To address certainly will trigger a spam notice. As well, the same will apply to any Reply-To address. Generally, sites will use a valid e-mail address with a "do not respond" notice. In the event that someone does respond, it is possible to automatically delete in-bound e-mail either by the e-mail server or by a process.

Comment: I think OP is not asking if he can match the From & To address. What he is asking is that once a user fills contact form on OP's website, which has an email field (user fills his email1). Website sends this form data "as" an email2 to OP's client. Now, OP is asking if via PHP/Something, if he sets this email2 (to client from Form)'s From: value as user's email1? So that client could easily click Reply to respond to user.

Comment: @DavChana There is some nuance in your post. I appreciate it! If a user fills out a form, the e-mail is sent from the web server domain using the SMTP server. Even if the *from* address is valid, anti-spam filters will filter the e-mail if the *from* address domain does not match the SMTP domain name. The obvious exception is where the users e-mail address domain does match the SMTP server domain name. *The form* in the OPs case, has not been clarified as to what the purpose of the form is. It may be best if the OP can provide more detail in this regard. Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. The form in question is a sort of contact form. The website visitor can send a comment or a question to the website "owner" (my client) about a specific product. It is quite important that the email is not confusing to my client about where it is from, so the most obvious thing is to make the email look like it's actually being sent by the visitor (with the from: being set to the visitor's email address).

Comment: @Cristian To avoid it being confusing to your client, no matter what the FROM: is, make the subject something like "from example.com contact page"

Comment: I've also created contact forms for clients like this; **never** spoof the `From` header, even if the client uses a mail service provided by you. It's confusing for your client and may land your server on spam blacklists. It's generally fine to use `Reply-To` instead, with a clear title as Steve said. If you're concerned about Reply-To, put the email address in the body of the email and make it *extremely clear* that your client must not use the reply button. "Do not reply to this email. Reply to [address] instead." or similar. They'll drop messages otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the user's email address as the 'from' address in a form notification email is not a good idea because it will trigger many spam filters due to a "spoofed" sender.  There are two systems which help detect spoofing:  SPF and DKIM.  SPF allows the email domain owner to specify which IP addresses and/or domains are valid senders for that domain. If the email message originates from an IP address not listed in the SPF record, email systems will (should) flag it as possible spam.

Also, DKIM is regarded as important by many email servers (Gmail et al) and is used to detect spoofed email addresses by adding a signature header which can be validated against a DNS record owned by the originating domain.

Recommendation: only send mail "from" email addresses that you control, and for which you have properly configured SPF and DKIM records.  This will help ensure recipient servers don't classify the messages as spam.

Good luck!